# Bogoliubov transformation in quantum optics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, second-quantization

I was trying to prove that linear optical component
are those whose Bogoliubov transformations take the particular form

$$a_i^{\dagger}=\sum^{n}_{j=1}U_{ij}a_j^{\dagger}$$

where $a_i^{\dagger}$ is the creation operator for the ith mode.

Using the Heisenberg representation and knowing that the Hamiltonian which generates an arbitrary linear optical evolution can be written as

$$H=\sum_{ij}h_{ij}a_i^{\dagger}a_j $$

where $h$ is an $m \times m$ hermitian matrix ($h^\dagger=h$). To that end, consider the Heisenberg equation for a set of operators $a_i^{\dagger}$

$$\frac{d}{dt}a_i^{\dagger}(t)=i [H,a_i^{\dagger}(t)]$$

By using the commutation relations $[a_i,a_j^{\dagger}]=\delta_{ij}$

$$\frac{d}{dt}a_i^{\dagger}(t)= \sum_j h_{ij} a_j^{\dagger}$$

And here is where I don't know how to solve this set of coupled first-order differential equations.

I appreciate any possible insights on how to proceed or if this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we are dealing here with a usual canonical transformation rather than the Bogoliubov transformation, which mixes creation and annihilation operators.

The last equation is a linear system of equations of the type:
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{x}(t)}{dt}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x},
$$
which can solved by standard methods. For example, one could assume the solutions in the form
$$
\mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{x}_0e^{\lambda t}
$$
substitute the into the equation, obtaining an eigenvalue problem, and find all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The general solution is then given by
$$
\mathbf{x}(t)=\sum_\nu\mathbf{x}_\nu e^{\lambda_\nu t}.
$$

One could also formally solve this equation by the method usually used for obtaining the evolution operator:
$$
\mathbf{x}(t)=e^{\mathbf{A}t}\mathbf{x}(0)
$$